# How to copy MDC values between Threads using SpringBoot version 1.3.8.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, version, threadpool, mdc

I need MDC Context to pass from one thread to another, I need it because when using @ASync it gets lost.

In the projects I have Spring version 1.3.8.RELEASE is used, this guy already comes with version 1.1.7 of LOGBack, in version 1.1.5 logback stopped supporting copying data to the child thread.

As can be seen here:
https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-422
, so it no longer does this by itself in my project.

There is one possibility, a very good possibility actually, which is using TASKDecorator.
However it is only available in version 4.3.x of SPRING:CORE, the version I use in the project only provides version 4.2.8.RELEASE.

Since I can't upgrade the Spring version and I can't downgrade logBack.

Is there another way out of this scenario? Copy context from MDC to Child thread without using TaskDecorator?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's that Portuguese text?

Comment: Please read [ask]. I do not even get what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, my translator failed, no need to be rude with someone's mistake, I appreciate your attention and tips.
I fixed my text

Comment: Thanks for deleting the rude answer "Yunnosch", it makes the community better!